# Blender displacement map as 3D-printed slices

Tags: texturing, uv, displacement

I'm working on a project with a clay printed building. The rendering should show those typical clay sausages that are visible in the wall. I'd like to use a displacement map for that and render with a material overwrite that I later use as an overlay in Photoshop. The other materials already have their bumpmaps and look ok so far.

Here is a video how 3D printed clay looks like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vixPA7GGQpM

The problem:
How can I create a material with a displacement map that is independent from the location, orientation or hight of the object. It should be a white texture and a horizontal bump.

Any idea how I can realize that? I appreciate any help :)